# String in notification is not updated

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager

What the application should do, is get a String from the editReminder `EditText` and send it to the `AlarmManager` using an intent. That works, the first time. 
But when you close the app and try it again, the notification does not use the string you just typed into the `EditText` but it uses the text you typed in the first time you ran the app.

How do we make the newly inserted text appear in the notification instead of the old text?

**MainActivity: the method executed on buttonclick**

```
public void setAlarm(View v) {
    //get user input
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editReminder);
    String reminder = editText.getText().toString();
    String snoozeString = getString(R.string.snooze_result);


    //the AlarmManager
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    //get date and time
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

    //sets time for alarm
    c.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    c.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
    c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    //pIntent to launch activity when alarm triggers
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.garden.DisplayNotification"); //(1)From here to DisplayNotification ...
    //DisplayNotification is the activity that is intended to be evoked
    //sometimes you have to use (this,DisplayNotification.class)?
    //when the alarm is triggered

    //assign an ID of 1, and add the text
    intent.putExtra("NotifID", 1);
    intent.putExtra("notification", reminder); //("STRING_I_NEED",strname)
    intent.putExtra("notifyAction", snoozeString); //string for the action button
    //set the flags so the mainactivity isn't started when the notification is triggered
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);


    PendingIntent displayIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            getBaseContext(), 0,
            intent, 0); //this intent instead of new Intent("com.garden.Reminder")


    //sets alarm
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            c.getTimeInMillis(), displayIntent);

    showConfirmDialog(v);

}
```

**DisplayNotification: executed when the alarm for the notification triggers**

```
package com.garden.gardenapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class DisplayNotification extends Activity {
/**
 * This activity is to display a notification only. It is called when
 * the system alarm goes off.
 */

//called when activity is first created
//don't forget to update the manifest!!
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    //get notification ID passed by MainActivity
    int notifID = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("NotifID");
    //----Oh of course, have to pass on the strings again.....-----
    //initialize strings (reminder is also used for notification text
    String reminderText = getIntent().getStringExtra("notification");
    String snoozeString = getIntent().getStringExtra("notifyAction");


    //pIntent to launch activity if user selects notification
    /** making a new Intent has to be done with (this, Reminder.class) instead
     * of ("com.garden.Reminder")... why? (otherwise the reminder text is not shown)
     */
    Intent reminderIntent = new Intent(this, Reminder.class); //(2)... and from here to Reminder ...
    reminderIntent.putExtra("NotifID", notifID);
    //pass on strings again in the intent
    reminderIntent.putExtra("notification", reminderText);
    //intent.putExtra("notifyAction",snoozeString); //---> in different intent


    PendingIntent reminderPIntent = PendingIntent
            .getActivity(this, 0, reminderIntent, 0);

    Intent actionIntent = new Intent(this, Reminder.class);
    actionIntent.putExtra("notifyAction", snoozeString); //("STRING_I_NEED", strName)
    //don't forget to pass the notifID also to the second intent
    actionIntent.putExtra("NotifID",notifID);
    PendingIntent actionPIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
            (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), actionIntent, 0);


    //create notification
    Notification notif = new Notification.Builder(this) //build the notification
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name)) //required
            .setContentText(reminderText) //required
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.garden) //required
            .setContentIntent(reminderPIntent)
            //associate pendingIntent with a gesture of NotificationCompat.Builder: click
            .addAction(R.drawable.pixel, "Snooze me", actionPIntent)
            //should be addAction(NotificationCompat.Action action)
            .setAutoCancel(true) //to be dismissed in the Reminder activity
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX) //to show the action buttons by default
            // .setVibrate(new long[] {200, 600, 200, 600})
            .build();

    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)
            getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    nm.notify(notifID, notif); //(int id, Notification notification);

    finish(); //because this doesn't have a GUI we don't need it anymore

}
}
```

(In the DisplayNotification class we split the strings into two intents, so when you click the snooze (notification action) button it fires a different intent than when you click on the notification)

We think it has to do with the AlarmManager not updating the String that comes with the intent or something. Because when we make a notification without the AlarmManager the app works perfectly fine. 
Please let me know if you need additional code.

Comment: Try moving your `EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editReminder);` to onCreate()

Comment: @Jas No, unfortunately that didn't help. (I made `editText` an instance variable and moved that line to onCreate() )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found it! You don't need to cancel the alarm manager, but you need to give the intent a flag [`FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT) to let the alarm manager update the intent with the new string you put in the intent.
So in this case, the `PendingIntent displayIntent` becomes

```
 PendingIntent displayIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            getBaseContext(), 0,
            intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

And that solved the problem of updating the string.